# How to make dynamic slideshow using php, mysql, css and html?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I wanna make dynamic slideshow with css and HTML. Image will be took by id from tb_image.

```
id int
image_name varchar (100)
image_path (100)
```

How to make dynamic slideshow using php, mysql, css and html?
or Can get image by id?

```
include "connnection.php";
$result = mysql_query("select * from slider");
?> 
    <div class="accordian">
    <?php 
        $i=1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="image_title">
                    </div>
                    <a href="#">
                    <img src="../img/<?php echo $i;?>.jpg" alt="" width="640" border="320"/> //I tried use this codes but it's error

                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="image_title">
                        <a href="#">Slide 2</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/<?php echo $_GET['id']=2;?>.jpg" alt="" width="640" border="320"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="image_title">
                        <a href="#">Slide 3</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/3.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="image_title">
                        <a href="#">Slide 4</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/4.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="image_title">
                        <a href="#">Slide 5</a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/5.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: yes,, codes above error

Comment: Include the error in your question :) @Sufi

Comment: I mean, that code didn't show the image but not any error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing exactly what you get back from your query, here's a guess:

Replace any of your `<img>`s with

```
<img src="../img/<?php echo $row['id']?>.jpg" alt="" width="640" border="320"/>
```

To "debug" your data, you can replace your while loop with

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  print_r($row);
}
```

This will print out any data found in each row.

You might also want to replace the deprecated `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: actually I don't wanna use loop, I wanna use id  in database to show / display image in web page with html tag.

Comment: Ok, something like `<img src="getImage.php?id=2" alt="" width="640" border="320"/>` then.

Comment: Iko, what's syntax for getImage.php ? Is that a link to get image?

Comment: @Sufi: you'd need to code getImage.php to get the corresponding image data from your database